# How do I flash the google coral dev board on my Mac?

Tags: mac

I am trying to flash the google coral with my mac, and I have downloaded the CP210x USB to UART Bridge Virtual COM Port (VCP) driver for Mac, but when I type in the screen /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART 115200 command on terminal, it says that there is no such file directory and terminates the screen, as opposed to the screen just showing up as blank. How do I fix this?